# Category on NSObject implementing protocol causes Unimplemented Method warnings

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, objective-c-category

If I define a subprotocol of the `NSObject` protocol with extra methods, then define and implement a category on `NSObject` that declares conformance to that protocol, I get warnings on compilation.  The compiler complains that my `NSObject` category doesn't implement all the methods declared in the `NSObject` protocol.

I don't understand why this is the case.  The `NSObject` class (in `<Foundation/NSObject.h>` declares that it conforms to the `NSObject` protocol (and, redundantly, that it implements these methods) - shouldn't that suffice?

What's the cause of the problem here?

Sample code - if you compile this, you'll see warnings on the `NSObject (CategoryToImplementMyProtocol)` implementation:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)myMethod;
@end

@interface NSObject (CategoryToImplementMyProtocol) <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation NSObject (CategoryToImplementMyProtocol)

- (void)myMethod 
{
    NSLog("A la peanut butter sandwiches!");
}

@end
```

I found a couple of questions addressing this, but all the answers were of the "do this workaround!" variety, not that "this is the cause of the problem" variety (or just plain wrong, despite being accepted...).  I know I can work around this.  I'd really like to understand *why* it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring adoption of the `<NSObject>` protocol again. The way protocols work in Objective-C (for better or for worse) is that a category implementation must implement all of the protocols that are specified in its interface.

In addition, protocol conformance is nominal rather than structural in Objective-C. That is to say, for a class to respond to the correct methods is not enough for it to have adopted that protocol.

***Edit***: Seems the example code has been changed, and I guess my answer isn't really relevant anymore.

Comment: Sorry!  Was a mistake when transcribing the code (if it's any consolation, I edited the question before seeing your answer - although I think it still makes sense, no?  Since `MyProtocol` is a subprotocol of `NSObject`).

Comment: :) But I think this case (which I didn't even realize would happen) is slightly more confusing than the one I answered. Since one doesn't have such a problem implementing such categories on classes which inherit `<NSObject>`, but do not adopt it themselves.

Comment: Yes, I still don't fully see the problem - why isn't enough that the main `NSObject` class I'm adding my category too already declares conformance to the `NSObject` protocol?

Comment: Yeah. (BTW, to make sure it wasn't a special case, I checked this with arbitrary protocols and classes, and it still fails). There just seems to be this fact about Objective-C, in which one category's interface cannot satisfy the constraints imposed by the interface of another.